# Logitech c170 webcam not working

Tags: webcam, vlc

I've connected a Logitech c170 webcam to a Raspberry Pi via an externally powered USB hub. It's running Raspbian Wheezy.

The camera is detected by the Pi when plugged in, and running `VLC` even causes the light on the camera to turn on. However, no image is displayed. I tried to grab an image using `streamer` and got the following output

```
files / video: JPEG (JFIF) / audio: none
libv4l2: error allocating conversion buffer
mmap: Cannot allocate memory
v4l2: ioctl(fildes = 3 "/dev/video0", request = VIDIOC_QBUF, struct v4l2_buffer *data = { index = 0, type = 0, bytesused = 0, flags = 0, field = V4L2_FIELD_ANY, timestamp = { 0 seconds }, timecode = { type = 0, flags = 0, frames = 0, seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0 }, sequence = 0, memory = 0, length = 0, input = 0 }) failed, Invalid argument (22, EINVAL) because the data->type argument was incorrectly specified
v4l2: oops: select timeout
```

And when I killed the program this error was printed many times

```
munmap: Invalid argument
```

Is there a driver missing?

Comment: Results with webcams (and USB devices in general) vary widely from one firmware rev to the next. Can you give us a "uname -a" ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem with libv4l2 and the Raspberry Pi.

The thing is it tries to allocate 256MB os RAM to make that conversion, which is all the memory of Model A and half of Model B.

If you are using model A your only hope is to create a Swap file/drive big enough for accomodating that conversion. 256MB should be the minimum.

If you are using model B, free up some memory closing programs or just do like model A and create some swap space.

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer but it may help and is too long for a comment.

I use [this one](http://www.geekbuying.com/item/Logitech-C170-Setup-5-Mega-Pixel-Wired-Camera-USB-Webcam-Web-Camera-312647.html) and it works fine using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("fswebcam -p YUYV -d /dev/video0 -i 0 -r 640x480 -S 40 --jpeg 75 --top-banner bottompic.jpg");`  That's in java just run the part in quotes from the command line.

I need to use -p YUYV and max I can get to work is 640x480.

If I don't skip around 40 frames the image isn't adjusted for lighting.

I'm not taking pics of people's bottoms, despite the name ;).